# $f$ has a local maximum value at every point in $(a,b)$. Show that $f$ is constant.

Tags: calculus

> Assume $f$ is continuous over $[a,b]$ and $f$ has a local maximum value at every point in $(a,b)$. Show that $f$ is constant.

Intuitively it makes sense that the constant function should be the constant function, but maybe one strategy is to prove that it is a necessary and sufficient condition on $f$. In other words, $f$ is continuous over $[a,b]$ and $f$ has a local maximum value at every point in $(a,b)$ if and only if $f$ is constant. Alternatively we can think of it as such: at every point $A_i$ over $[a,b]$, there exists some interval $J_i$ such that $A_i$ is greater than or equal to every value in of $f$ in $J_i$.

I am unsure which route to take to solve this.

Comment: It's not a local maximum--that's not possible with a constant function since the sign of the derivative never changes (it's always $0$)--there are no local extrema.

Comment: @Jared Every point for a constant function is a local maximum, though.

Comment: @Jared I think this is the following definition they're using for $f$ having local maxima at $x=x^*$: $$(\exists \epsilon > 0)(\forall x \in \Bbb{R})(\lvert x-x^* \rvert < \epsilon \implies f(x^*) \geq f(x))$$ It's the same definiton as used [in this Math StackExchange question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/359553/definition-of-local-maxima-local-minima).

Comment: @NobleMushtak I'm not sure...but it would seem to me that this would label inflection points where $f'(x) =0$ as local extrema...is that wrong (I mean I'm fairly certain that inflection points are _not_ local extrema)?

Comment: @Jared Inflection points are in no way local extrema. That definition of local maximum would not include inflection points as local extrema.

Comment: @user19405892 Every point for a constant function is an _absolute_ maximum (and minimum)--not local (at least in my opinion--that may be wrong it sounds like though).

Comment: @Jared Aren't all absolute maximums also local maximums, though? Also, [this paper](http://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/bhrnds/publ_papers/BGN.pdf) seems to deal with this issue, but it seems really complicated. I'll try to post an easier explanation if I can understand the paper.

Comment: @NobleMushtak No, absolute extrema are definitely _not_ necessarily local extrema.  _Usually_ when we talk about $\mathbb{R}\mapsto\mathbb{R}$ functions, _and_ the function is differentiable (therefore continuous) then the absolute extrema over the domain $(-\infty, \infty)$, _if they exist_, will be a local extrema.

Comment: @Jared I never said that absolute extreme are local extrema.

Comment: ahh, sorry, I meant to address @NobleMushtak.

Comment: I'm wondering what can be said if $f$ is not assumed to be continuous. So far I have (1)When $a<a'<b<b'$, the set$ f[a',b']$ is countable and well-ordered (by the usual order on $R$), and (2) The image of $(a,b)$ is countable.

Comment: @Jared Can you give an example of an absolute maximum that would not fit the definition of local maximum I have above? I don't see how an absolute maximum would not fit that definition since an absolute maximum has $f(x^*) \geq f(x)$ for all $x$ in the domain.

Comment: @NobleMushtak Consider the function $f(x) = x^3$ over the domain $x \in [-3, 3]$.  The absolute maximum is at $x = 3$ and has a value of $27$ and the absolute minimum occurs at $x = -3$ and has a value of $-27$.  Neither of these are local extrema since the function $f(x) = x^3$ has no local extrema.  If you're saying that we should only consider $x$ inside the given domain (which your definition does not) then yes, those two points satisfy your definition of local extrema--but I've never seen any text book or Calculus course (at any level) that would consider those local extrema.

Comment: @Jared Oh...That makes sense! Thanks for the example! If I changed my definition to $\forall x \in D$ where $D$ was the domain of $f$, then that example would also say that those absolute extrema are not local extrema since there's no positive interval around $-3$ or $3$ as they're on the boundary of the domain. However, that doesn't apply to this because all of the points said to be local maximums are in $(a, b)$ while the domain is $[a, b]$, so the hypothesis never says that a local maximum is on the boundary of the domain.

Answer (score 2):

Let $c\in [a,b]$ be a point where $f$ attains its *global* minimum value $m$.

Let $A = \{ x \in [a,c] : f(y)=m \text{ for all } y\in [x,c] \}$ and let $a'=\inf A$.

Since $f$ is continuous, $f(a')=m$ and so $a'\in A$ and $A=[a',c]$.

Since $a'$ is a local maximum, there is an interval $I$ around $a'$ such that $f(x)\le f(a')=m$ for all $x \in I$. This implies that $f(x)=m$ for all $x \in I$. Therefore, $a'=a$, because otherwise $I$ would contain a point of $A$ less than $a'$. Thus, $A=[a,c]$.

Analogously, by considering $B = \{ x \in [c,b] : f(y)=m \text{ for all } y\in [c,x] \}$, we get that $b'=\sup B=b$ and $B=[c,b]$.

Therefore, $f$ is constant in $[a,b]$, because $[a,b]=[a,c]\cup[c,b]=A\cup B$ and $f$ is constant, equal to $m$, in $A\cup B$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $f$ has local maximum at every $x \in (a,b)$. Let $U \subset (a,b)$ be the open set for which $x$ is a local maximum. Let $y$ be different from $x$ and in $U$. WLOG suppose $y>x$. Suppose $f(x) \not = f(y)$. Let $V$ be the open set for which $y$ is a local maximum. Then on $V \cap U$ both $x,y$ are local maximums. However, $x<y$ and $y \in U \cap V \subset U$ implies $f(x)\geq f(y)$ but $U \cap V \subset V$ and $x<y$ implies $f(x)\leq f(y)$; hence $f(x) = f(y)$. Since this we can do this for any $x \in (a,b)$ we are done i.e $f$ is constant on $(a,b)$.

Remark: A more general statement is that if $X$ is a connected topological space, $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous (and $\mathbb{R}$ has the usual topology) and $f$ is local constant, then $f$ is constant.

Comment: What if $V\cap U=\emptyset$?

Comment: @BigbearZzz $y$ was chosen to be in $U$ so there is no way that this can happen.

Comment: Opps sorry I missed the part.

Comment: @BigbearZzz: No problem.

Comment: I read your last statement saying that "for any $x,y\in(a,b)$" so I though you mean $x,y$ are arbitrary.

Comment: @BigbearZzz: Yeah, I should fix the english on that since it is sort of misleading.

Comment: Just a little comment. Your last implication about proving for any $x\in(a,b),\ \ f$ is locally constant implies that $f$ is globally constant need a fact about the connectedness (or path-connectedness) of $(a,b)$, which might be non-trivial for the OP.

Comment: @FaraadArmwood, $f$ is not assumed to be differentiable.

Comment: @User001 I don't think he's ever used the fact though.

Comment: @User001: Yeah, I just made an edit but I never used it.

Comment: @BigbearZzz: Yeah, there is a little more to be added but it's not too difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: you need to break the continuity of $f$.

Also, do not assume that $f$ is differentiable -- you can't use that $f'(x) = 0$.